# Computing the first 2 terms of the Taylor series exp. for the center manifold & find the reduced equation on the center manifold.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, linearization

I am having difficulty solving the problem below. It is from Meiss Dynamics book. Can I please receive help solving the following system? Thank you

Consider the system $$x' = y$$ $$y'=-y+ax^2 + bxy.$$ Compute the first two terms of the Taylor series expansion for the center manifold and find the reduced equation on the center manifold. For what values of $a$ and $b$ is the origin stable? Unstable? Semi-stable? Note the linearization at the origin is not in Jordan Canonical Form.

Comment: Should your first equation read $x' = y$?

Comment: yes, correct. Sorry about that @RobertLewis

Comment: Also, perhaps the second equation should read $y' = -x + ax^2 + bxy$?  Otherwise I can't see how the system has a center at $(0, 0)$.  Cheers!

Comment: The problem from the book states what I have posted, is it possible the authors made a mistake then? @RobertLewis

Comment: It may indeed be that the authors  did err,  I'll try to explain in my answer.

Comment: OK check out what I have done so far in terms of an answer.  This explains why the system as given has no center at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @RobertLewis If $y' = - x + ax^2 + bxy$, then the whole space would be the center manifold, in which case we have found an explicit center manifold.

Comment: @Hetebrij:  but in that case there is also a zero at $(a^{-1}, 0)$.

Comment: @RobertLewis True, but if my mental arithmetic are correct, the second zero at $(a^{-1},0)$ is a saddle.

Comment: @Hetebrij: yes that is exactly what I suspected as well.

Comment: @brucemcmc If you look at this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217709/252750 , can you see how you could apply this to your system?

Comment: @Hetebrij yes thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equilibrium is attained at the solutions for

$$
\cases{
y=0\\
-y+a x^2+b x y = 0
}
$$

so $(0,0)$ is the equilibrium point. To qualify it we compute the jacobian at this point giving

$$
J = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues $(1,\ 0)$ so the equilibrium manifold is one-dimensional. To find this manifold we proceed as follows.

For the dynamical system

$$
\cases{
\dot x=f(x,y)\\
\dot y=g(x,y)
}
$$

Proposing the solution

$$
y=h(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k
$$

we have

$$
\dot y=h_x(x)\dot x = h_x(x)f(x,h(x))=g(x,h(x))
$$

assuming $n=4$ equating the $x$ powers we arrive at

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a_1&=&0 \\
a_2 &=& a \\
a_3 &=& a b-2 a^2\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving we have

$$
h(x) = a x^2+a(b-2a) x^3+ O(x^4)
$$

as a near origin approximation.

Follows a plot showing the stream plot for $a = -\frac 12, b = 1$ showing in thick blue a near origin center manifold segment and in red dashed, a path beginning at $(0.5,0.5)$

NOTE

The central manifold approximate flow for $n=4$ is given by

$$
\dot x = h(x) = a x^2+a (b-2a) x^3+ O(x^4)
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and thorough explanation Cesareo!

Comment: The eigenvalues are $0$ and $-1$, we cannot infer anything about stability yet. Which is why we need to consider the flow on the center manifold. Also, the last term in the second equation should be $b x y$.

Comment: Thanks by the considerations. With $n=4$ the flow at the center manifold is given by $  \dot x = h(x)\approx a x^2+a(b-2a)x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that

$a \ne 0, \tag 1$

for reasons which will become clear in what follows.  Under this assumption, the system

$\dot x = y, \tag 2$

$\dot y = -y + ax^2 + bxy ,\tag 3$

has a single equilibrium point at $(0, 0)$, for setting

$\dot x = \dot y = 0, \tag 4$

we see from (2) that

$y = 0, \tag 5$

and then from (3) that

$ax^2 = 0, \tag 6$

whence

$x = 0. \tag 7$

Here we have used assumption (1), for without it we cannot conclude that the critical set of the system (2)-(3) is a single point.

The Jacobian matrix of this system at $(x, y)$ is given by

$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2ax + by & bx - 1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 8$

at $(0, 0)$ this becomes

$J(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 &  -1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 9$

this matrix has characteristic polynomial

$\det \left(  \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ 0 &  -1 - \lambda \end{bmatrix}  \right) = \lambda(\lambda + 1); \tag{10}$

the roots of this polynomial are

$\lambda = 0, -1, \tag{11}$

both of which are real.  Thus $(0, 0)$ is not a center.

There has been some discussion in the comments suggesting that perhaps the system (2)-(3) should be replaced with

$\dot x = y, \tag{12}$

$\dot y = -x + ax^2 + bxy; \tag{13}$

this system has to zeroes; from (12) we have

$y = 0, \tag{12}$

and then (13) becomes

$0 = -x + ax^2 = x(ax - 1), \tag{13}$

whence

$x = 0, a^{-1}; \tag{14}$

therefore we need inspect the two zeroes $(0, 0)$ and $(a^{-1}, 0)$.

In this case the Jacobian matrix takes the form

$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 + 2ax + by & bx \end{bmatrix}, \tag{15}$

and we have

$J(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1  & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{16}$

the characteristic polynomial is now

$\det \left(  \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ -1 &  -\lambda \end{bmatrix}  \right) = \lambda^2 + 1, \tag{17}$

and the roots are

$\lambda = \pm i, \tag{18}$

so that $(0, 0)$ is in fact a center.

The Jacobian at $(a^{-1}, 0)$ is

$J(a^{-1}, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1  & ba^{-1} \end{bmatrix}, \tag{19}$

with characteristic polynomial

$\det \left (  \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ 1  & ba^{-1} - \lambda \end{bmatrix} \right ) = \lambda^2 - a^{-1}b\lambda - 1, \tag{20}$

the roots of which are

$\lambda = \dfrac{a^{-1}b \pm \sqrt{b^2 a^{-2} + 4}}{2}. \tag{21}$

More to follow.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation Robert!